# Change JSESSSIONID name IN weblogic 10.3.4 and cause nullpointer exception in request.getsession(false)

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, weblogic, oracle-adf

i change the JSESSIONID Name in weblogic 10.3.4 in weblogic.xml in descriptor with:

```
              <session-descriptor>
                <cookie-name>JSESSIONID_SEG</cookie-name>
        </session-descriptor>
```

how to say the documentation in ADF the session is normal , librarys, filters , etc.
but in servlets i have the problem that in code:

```
request.getSession(false)
```

return null, please help i change again to jessionid name o delete the tags in weblogic.xml and works fine , why? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

i resolve this issue use the getSessionMap() in facescontext